# Angular 7 - Only "dist" folder is rendering on browser but not "src" folder with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Hi i am starting a project of nodejs app with angular7. This is my mail server.js file in nodejs

```
var express = require('express'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/angular/src'));

require('./app/routes')(router);

app.use(router);



app.listen(2233, function(){
    console.log('app started on 2233');
});
```

This line `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/angular/src'));` indicates that i want to render src folder inside angular folder on nodejs app load but this is rendering blank screen. When i run `ng build` and change it to `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/angular/dist'));` then start working.

All the tutorial showing to run `ng build` and run angular inside node but why can i use `src` folder inside nodejs.

Comment: Why would you need to use your `src` files though? Your built files are in the `dist` folder

Comment: @wentjun As per my knowledge (please corrent me if i am wrong) we use `ng build` to minify the files and use light weight app on production. When we create new project it opens on browser on `http://localhost:4200/` but that works on `src` folder then on production we use `ng build` and serve `dist` folder. I am using `src` folder as its hard to run `ng build` after every small change. I will run `ng build` and change it to `dist` on production. And also there is little curiosity why its not working on `src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` folder is used during development. They are actual source files which has your programs in readable format.

`dist` is generated when you do ng build, it will have all your src files, assets and your node modules combined and minified into a small package.

So, there is no point of having src in your deployment

**Updated**:
When you are in development as you said for every small change minfying the code and building whole code again takes lot of time. So, when we do `ng serve` it will just convert  files to js but no minification or other things will happen.

Why src will not work if you copy it for deployment is, src contains .ts files if you are using latest Angular and you have to transpile it to JS with some modifications required in order for it to be understandable by browser.

Comment: Amazing catch. Any solution how can i do that without `ng build` ??

Comment: You can use task runners like gulp or grunt to build pack on your own.

Comment: i am using pm2. so can i do define something so that `ng build` run internally when i use pm2 reload ??

Comment: Yes, you can do that easily with task runners @Gaurav

Comment: task runners has nothing to do with pm2 reload

Comment: pm2 will trigger your node script. So, from your node script you can invoke ng build and get it done. Rest of the things will work normally. Only thing is you have to add a task in your node script